# Junit file path

Tags: maven, junit, resources, filepath

I am passing a filePath to JUnit as follows

```
public static void copyFile() throws IOException 

  {
    String inputFileName = "myproj/src/test/resources/list.csv";
    File file = new File(inputFileName);
    File newFile = new File(new File("/tmp"), file.getName());
    FileUtils.copyFile(file, newFile);
  }
```

The package Structure is as follows.

I am running Test.java from IDE (IntelliJ) and it runs fine but when I do mvn clean install i get the below exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Source 'myproj/src/test/resources/list.csv' does not exist
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1004)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:968)
    at ......copyFile(Test.java:21)
```

Can some one please let me know how am i suppose to give path name in the JUnit.

Comment: You get that exception from `mvn clean install`?  What path is your junit test class in?

Comment: Use `getResourceAsStream` method.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is a strong hint to the problem... the file does not exist at that path.

In your IDE the working directory is set such that your relative path (myproj/src/test/resources/list.csv) resolves correctly.

The Maven task is running from a different working directory, presumably from myproj, so the file path cannot be resolved.

You have a couple of possibilities:

1. Use an absolute path
2. Load the resource from the classpath instead, using getResourceAsStream https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)
3. Build different relative paths based on the environment (this is a bad solution)